# temporal: when testing, how do I pass context into workflows and activities?

Tags: go, testing, temporal-workflow

I'm writing an integration test for a temporal workflow and using the golang sdk. My workflow has an activity which includes the following code:

```golang
   stackEnv, ok := ctx.Value("stackEnv").(*StackEnv)
    if !ok {
        return nil, errors.New("stackEnv not configured")
    }
```

In my test I create a `TestWorkflowEnvironment` and run my workflow with `s.env.ExecuteWorkflow(EntityCreateWorkflow, wfParams)`. However I get an error in my test that `stackEnv not configured` because the `context.Context` the activity is running with in the test environment does not have `stackEnv` set on it. How do I specify a custom context to my `TestWorkflowEnvironment`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `TestWorkflowEnvironment.SetWorkerOptions()` API.

In production code, the context parameter is specified on the worker that executes workflows, e.g.:

```golang
    ctx := context.WithValue(context.Background(), "stackEnv", stackEnv)

    worker.New(stackEnv.Temporal, string(taskQueueName), worker.Options{
        BackgroundActivityContext: ctx,
    })
```

In the `WorkflowTestEnvironment`, a worker is simulated. We can specify options to it with `SetWorkerOptions()`, e.g.:

```golang
    ctx := context.WithValue(context.Background(), "stackEnv", StackEnv)

    s.env.SetWorkerOptions(worker.Options{
        BackgroundActivityContext: ctx,
    })
```

(where `s.env` is the temporal `testsuite.TestWorkflowEnvironment`)

Comment: How would you do this when your testing a child workflow as if it's a parent workflow in a unit test and it relies on something being defined in the context.  In otherwords, how do you initialize values into the context of the workflow when you call ExecuteWorkflow

Answer (score 3):

Patrick's answer is absolutely correct.

I would also recommend looking into implementing activities as members of a structure. This way passing dependencies to them doesn't require messing with context.

See the [greetings sample](https://github.com/temporalio/samples-go/tree/master/greetings) that uses this technique.